# How to remove burnt coffee from the bottom of a coffeepot?

Tags: cleaning, drinks

The coffee burnt onto the bottom of my coffeepot, and I can't find a method to get it clean. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I am not certain I understand what you are asking here.  Are you saying the coffepot caught fire and burned the floor, that your coffee boiled over onto the floor, or that you had it sitting on the floor, and it has burnth the floor?  Or something else?

Comment: Do you mean “on the bottom of the carafe”?

Comment: sorry I edit that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience with cooked-on, scorched coffee inside the carafe of a coffee machine is that it will wipe out if soaked in plain water, then wiped with a paper towel.  Don't use any kind of abrasive (Scotch-Brite, Hannah's Helper, etc.), or scouring powder; this may cause the carafe to shatter when heated.  Worst case, copper wool (Chore Boy or similar) shouldn't scratch the glass (copper is much softer than glass), but I'd still call that a last resort, as copper may deposit on the glass and alter the taste of the coffee.

As noted in another answer, soaking with vinegar (before scrubbing) may help, though I wouldn't add the baking soda until the soak is done; otherwise you neutralize the vinegar's cleaning ability.  Coca-Cola works because of the phosphoric acid it contains; you can get floor cleaners that contain this at higher strength, but I'd be very wary of using those in a coffee carafe; it would require a very thorough rinse to avoid changing the taste of the coffee.

Answer (score 0):

### Salt

Salt is surprisingly good at getting stuff stuck to pots, coffee or not.

#### Method 1: salt and ice

- Pour salt into the coffee pot, 1/4 cup should do.
- Put some ice cubes (gently) into the coffee pot.

  - You may add some vinegar or lemon for particularly persistent stains.
- Smoothly swirl the mixture inside of the carafe for a few minutes to gradually break up the stain and debris.
- Rinse and wipe.

#### Method 2: salt and heat

- pour enough salt into the coffee pot to cover the bottom.
- pour in enough water to cover the salt
- heat the coffee pot until enough water evaporates that the salt is no longer covered

  - the salt should be sort of caked on, but not dry
- allow the coffee pot to cool and wipe out the moist salt, this should bring with it any burnt remnants.

Answer (score -1):

You can pour coca-cola or baking-soda with vinegar and let them soak.

Comment: Do you know how much cola or baking soda/vinegar would be needed, as well as how long it should soak for?

Comment: Well it depends the thickness of the burn (from personal experience)... and about the time... its also depends... when it seems to be more soft!

Comment: Baking Soda will neutralize vinegar.

Answer (score -1):

i found fabric softener (i.e. wet dryer sheet) does the trick in removing burned on stuff nicely.

Comment: that doesn't work but thanks!